# Writing AND in query for Solr

Tags: solr

I'd like to send a query to Local Solr. Currently I'm sending this:

http://localhost:9001/solrfacetsearch/master_Shop/select/?q=keyword_text_mv%3Aapple&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&qt=geo&lat=52.398&long=4.93653&radius=2000&debugQuery=true.

As you can see, the query is `keyword_text_mv : apple`

I'd like to send `apple AND orange`.

How would I write this? Would the following be ok?

http://localhost:9001/solrfacetsearch/master_Shop/select/?q=keyword_text_mv%3Aapple AND orange&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&qt=geo&lat=52.398&long=4.93653&radius=2000&debugQuery=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways. For example:
- use the `+apple +orange`
- or set the default Option with `q={!lucene q.op=AND df=keyword_text_mv}`
->Follow the link, posted by zeropage, which is helpful -> http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Answer (score 5):

I find it much easier just to use bracket based logical grouping together with boolean statements, in other words your query would turn in to:

```
keyword_text_mv:(apple AND orange)
```

however this is a bit weird, not sure something can have two values at the same time? I think you might be looking for:

```
keyword_text_mv:(apple OR orange)
```

perhaps?

Comment: If `keyword_text_mv` is tokenized or multiValued or both then `AND` is fine in this context.